# RadAjaxManager AJAX Request Fails Roughly 10% of the time

Tags: .net, ajax, vb.net, telerik

I have a web application which uses a RadAjaxManager to populate RadComboBox controls as a user makes selections on one of my pages.  This works correctly most of the time however roughly 10% of the time the AJAX call seems to fire but no values are loaded into the target RadComboBox.  If the browser is closed and the page accessed again this behavior seems to continue but after a few minutes and another browser refresh everything works fine once again.

Here are the Ajax settings for the RadComboBox initiating the AJAX request:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rcmbMarket">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rcmbApplicationField" 
                LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ApplicationFieldSource" 
                LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Here is the markup for the initiating and traget combo boxes:

```
<asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Center" ID="ProductRow3">
    <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="MarketLabelCell">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMarket" runat="server" Text="Market: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldMarket" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rcmbMarket" 
            ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="grpMain"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="MarketDDLCell">
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbMarket" runat="server" AllowCustomText="false" DataSourceID="MarketSource" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false"
            DataTextField="MarketDesc" DataValueField="pkMarketID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Market_Check">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="" Value="" />
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MarketSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuoteProdConn %>" SelectCommand="SELECT pkMarketID, MarketDesc FROM Data.Market WHERE Active = 'True' ORDER BY MarketDesc ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="ApplicationLabelCell">
        <asp:Label ID="lblApplicationField" runat="server" Text="Application Field:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldAppField" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rcmbApplicationField" 
            ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="grpMain"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell Width="25%" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="ApplicationTextCell">
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcmbApplicationField" runat="server" AllowCustomText="false" DataSourceID="ApplicationFieldSource" ExpandDirection="Down"
            AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="AppDescription" DataValueField="pkAppFieldID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CausesValidation="false" MaxHeight="300px">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="" Value="" />
            </Items>    
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ApplicationFieldSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuoteProdConn %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Here is the code behind for the Market_Check sub called when the selected index of the market combo box is changed:

```
Protected Sub Market_Check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim tmpItem As New Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem("", "")
    ApplicationFieldSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT pkAppFieldID, AppDescription FROM Data.ApplicationField WHERE Active = 'True' AND fkMarketID = " & rcmbMarket.SelectedValue.ToString() & " ORDER BY AppDescription ASC "
    ApplicationFieldSource.DataBind()
    rcmbApplicationField.Items.Clear()
    rcmbApplicationField.Items.Add(tmpItem)
    rcmbApplicationField.DataBind()

End Sub
```

It is all pretty simple so I am really not sure why my this issue is happening.  Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get an answer - Telerik is very good about getting back to you

Comment: Are you using RadCompression?  If so, I've found it can sometimes cause similar issues.  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/compression.html

Comment: Can you include details about your environment such as IIS and .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update ApplicationFieldSource with Telerik Ajax also.

Anyway this approach is very tricky, today you have so much client server 
technologies far much better than RadAjaxManager/MS ASP.NET ajax, for example
simple jQuery call to simple webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried checking the request and response property with FireBug (Net tab) or Fiddler? That can provide some more insight if it is happening with some selected values of rcmbMarket items (i.e. some bad data in database). Also, check if the page is not too heavy to post. RadAjaxManager posts full page even in ajax request.